# Radio button positioned after text field with onChange loses the value selected

Tags: javascript, xpages

I have the following piece of code that presents a text field with an onChange event followed by a radio button. When the user enters a value into the text field and then clicks on the radio button field the value they selected in the radio button is lost.

To get around this we added a button that the user has to click before they select their choice on the radio button.

This is not a great workaround and I want to get rid of it. How do I make this work so that when they exit the text field and click on the following radio button, the value they selected in the radio button remains selected?

```
<xp:inputText id="shortAnswerCurrency" styleClass="short-answer form-control" value="#{compositeData.dataSource[compositeData.dataBinding]}" disableClientSideValidation="true">
            <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:compositeData.QuestionDoc.getItemValueString("qType") == "Currency"}]]></xp:this.rendered>
            <xp:this.required><![CDATA[#{javascript:compositeData.QuestionDoc.getItemValueString("qRequire") == "Yes";}]]></xp:this.required>
            <xp:this.validators>
                <xp:validateRequired message="This question is required. Please enter a response."></xp:validateRequired>
            </xp:this.validators>
            <xp:this.converter>
                <xp:convertNumber type="currency" integerOnly="false" currencySymbol="$" currencyCode="USD"></xp:convertNumber>
            </xp:this.converter>
            <xp:this.attrs>
                <xp:attr name="placeholder" value="$"></xp:attr>
            </xp:this.attrs>
            <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="myQuestions" disableValidators="true" onComplete="$('.datePickerDiv input').datepicker({format: 'MM dd, yyyy'});">
                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.put(compositeData.QuestionDoc.getItemValueString("qMapping"), getComponent("shortAnswerCurrency").value);}]]></xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:inputText>
        <xp:button id="currencyButton" value="Enter" styleClass="btn btn-md btn-default">
            <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:compositeData.QuestionDoc.getItemValueString("qType") == "Currency"}]]></xp:this.rendered>
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="myQuestions" disableValidators="true">
                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.put(compositeData.QuestionDoc.getItemValueString("qMapping"), getComponent("shortAnswerCurrency").value);}]]></xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>

<xp:radioGroup id="radioValue" value="#{compositeData.dataSource[compositeData.dataBinding]}" styleClass="long-radiolist" disableClientSideValidation="true">
            <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:compositeData.QuestionDoc.getItemValueString("qType") == "Radio"}]]></xp:this.rendered>
            <xp:this.required><![CDATA[#{javascript:compositeData.QuestionDoc.getItemValueString("qRequire") == "Yes";}]]></xp:this.required>
            <xp:this.validators>
                <xp:validateRequired message="This question is required. Please select a response."></xp:validateRequired>
            </xp:this.validators>
            <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="myQuestions" disableValidators="true" onComplete="$('.datePickerDiv input').datepicker({format: 'MM dd, yyyy'});">
                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.put(compositeData.QuestionDoc.getItemValueString("qMapping"), getComponent("radioValue").value);}]]></xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
            <xp:selectItems>
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:compositeData.QuestionDoc.getItemValue("qValues")}]]></xp:this.value>
            </xp:selectItems>
        </xp:radioGroup>
```

Comment: Did you bind two elements to the same value (object) on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

In the radiobutton you submit=true in the event handler.
getComponent("radioValue").value is maybe the wrong one and you need getComponent("radioValue").getSubmittedValue()

I have

Comment: may be this of use, a SSJS function which give you the value of an component, without bothering about which value you need, https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=getcomponentvalue

Comment: Frank, I tried your idea and it didn't work. Based on the edit I made (click on "edited n minutes ago"), the new behavior is not firing the onChange for the Radio Button and it is not retaining the value selected. I assume that this is due to the onChange event firing for the text box and causing the onChange for the Radio button to be ignored. Is there any way around this?

Comment: depends on where your refreshId 'myQuestions' is pointing? Is that a panel? Is it around the input and radiobutton?

Comment: myQuestions is a panel and this code is inside a CC inside the panel

Comment: yes that was I expecting ;-) So you are updating on the radiobutton the panel and also the fields. Do you know if getSubmittedValue() on the onChange of the radiobutton returns something or does the getValue() return something. Just print it to the console print(getComponent('radiobutton').getSubmittedValue())

Comment: getSubmittedValue() returns "Yes" or "No" if you click on it twice. It does not return anything on the first click after leaving the text field. Also using .value acts the same way, you have to click it twice for the event to fire